# There's a weird splatter of colours/chroma, does anybody know what it is?

Tags: modeling

[image]

Here's my specs:

Device name Omen
Processor   11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11800H @ 2.30GHz   2.30 GHz
Installed RAM   16.0 GB (15.6 GB usable)
Device ID   EA7E888D-9981-4A6A-B04E-C92BDA356CE3
Product ID  00342-20772-93772-AAOEM
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch   No pen or touch input is available for this display